# Graph API directly from Blazor WASM using Azure AD B2C

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, blazor-webassembly

I found out it is not possible to use the Graph API directly from Blazor WASM when using Azure AD B2C for authentication. This is only enabled for Azure AD.
To get around this problem you will have to make protected endpoints in your backend controllers and call the MS Graph API from there using clientid+secret credentials and send them back to the webassembly client.
Maybe сan someone share how to implement all this?

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book/technologie recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)